# Why does BigQuery fail to parse an Avro file that is accepted by avro-tools?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, avro, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to export google cloud datastore data to Avro files in google cloud storage and then load those files into BigQuery.

Firstly, I know that Big Query loads datastore backups. This has several disadvantages that I'd like to avoid:

- [Backup tool is closed source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring)
- Backup tool format is undocumented.
- Backup tool format cannot be read directly by Dataflow
- [Backup scheduling for appengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups) is in (apparently perpetual) alpha.
- It is possible to [implement your own backup handler](https://eshlox.net/2013/10/12/google-app-engine-creating-and-restoring-a-backup-of-datastore/) in appengine, but it is fire and forget. You won't know when exactly the backup has finished or what the file name will be.

With the motivation clarified for this experiment here is my Dataflow Pipeline to export the data to avro format:

```java
package com.example.dataflow;

import com.google.api.services.datastore.DatastoreV1;
import com.google.api.services.datastore.DatastoreV1.Entity;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.AvroIO;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.DatastoreIO;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.Read;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader;
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter;
import org.apache.avro.file.SeekableByteArrayInput;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.protobuf.ProtobufData;
import org.apache.avro.protobuf.ProtobufDatumWriter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class GCDSEntitiesToAvroSSCCEPipeline {

    private static final String GCS_TARGET_URI = "gs://myBucket/datastore/dummy";
    private static final String ENTITY_KIND = "Dummy";

    private static Schema getSchema() {
        return ProtobufData.get().getSchema(Entity.class);
    }

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GCDSEntitiesToAvroSSCCEPipeline.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create();
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        DatastoreV1.Query.Builder q = DatastoreV1.Query.newBuilder()
                .addKind(DatastoreV1.KindExpression.newBuilder().setName(ENTITY_KIND));

        p.apply(Read.named("DatastoreQuery").from(DatastoreIO.source()
                .withDataset(options.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class).getProject())
                .withQuery(q.build())))
            .apply(ParDo.named("ProtoBufToAvro").of(new ProtoBufToAvro()))
            .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(getSchema()))
            .apply(AvroIO.Write.named("WriteToAvro")
                    .to(GCS_TARGET_URI)
                    .withSchema(getSchema())
                    .withSuffix(".avro"));
        p.run();

    }

    private static class ProtoBufToAvro extends DoFn<Entity, GenericRecord> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            Schema schema = getSchema();
            ProtobufDatumWriter<Entity> pbWriter = new ProtobufDatumWriter<>(Entity.class);
            DataFileWriter<Entity> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(pbWriter);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            dataFileWriter.create(schema, bos);
            dataFileWriter.append(c.element());
            dataFileWriter.close();

            DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
            DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(
                    new SeekableByteArrayInput(bos.toByteArray()), datumReader);

            c.output(dataFileReader.next());

        }
    }
}
```

The pipeline runs fine, however when I try to load the resultant Avro file into big query I get the following error:

```
bq load --project_id=roodev001 --source_format=AVRO dummy.dummy_1 gs://roodev001.appspot.com/datastore/dummy-00000-of-00001.avro
Waiting on bqjob_r5c9b81a49572a53b_00000154951eb523_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'roodev001:bqjob_r5c9b81a49572a53b_00000154951eb523_1': The Apache Avro library failed to parse file
gs://roodev001.appspot.com/datastore/dummy-00000-of-00001.avro.
```

However if I load the resultant avro file with avro tool, everything is just fine:

```
avro-tools tojson datastore-dummy-00000-of-00001.avro | head
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
{"key":{"com.google.api.services.datastore.DatastoreV1$.Key":{"partition_id":{"com.google.api.services.datastore.DatastoreV1$.PartitionId":{"dataset_id":"s~roodev001","namespace":""}},"path_element":[{"kind":"Dummy","id":4503905778008064,"name":""}]}},"property":[{"name":"number","value":{"boolean_value":false,"integer_value":879,"double_value":0.0,"timestamp_microseconds_value":0,"key_value":null,"blob_key_value":"","string_value":"","blob_value":"","entity_value":null,"list_value":[],"meaning":0,"indexed":true}}]}
...
```

I used this code to populate the datastore with dummy data before running the Dataflow pipeline:

```java
package com.example.datastore;

import com.google.gcloud.AuthCredentials;
import com.google.gcloud.datastore.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.builder()
            .projectId("myProjectId")
            .authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createApplicationDefaults())
            .build().service();

    KeyFactory dummyKeyFactory = datastore.newKeyFactory().kind("Dummy");


    Batch batch = datastore.newBatch();
    int batchCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++){
        IncompleteKey key = dummyKeyFactory.newKey();
        System.out.println("adding entity " + i);
        batch.add(Entity.builder(key).set("number", i).build());
        batchCount++;
        if (batchCount > 99) {
            batch.submit();
            batch = datastore.newBatch();
            batchCount = 0;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("done");

}
```

So why is BigQuery rejecting my avro files?

Comment: What codec is used in the avro file for block compression? BigQuery supports only DEFLATE at the moment. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-formats#avro_format.

Comment: @MichaelSheldon As far as I can tell there is no block compression used in the file. The Avro tools `getmeta` command does not print a value for `avro.codec`.

Comment: Heres a link to the output avro file of dummy entities: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4dY1dqkTY14VmZnc0pCUjNrMEE

Comment: I know you probably have good reasons that you are choosing to do things this way, but have you considered having your Dataflow pipeline write directly to BigQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BigQuery uses the C++ Avro library, and apparently it doesn't like the "$" in the namespace. Here's the error message:

Invalid namespace: com.google.api.services.datastore.DatastoreV1$

We're working on getting these Avro error messages out to the end user.

Comment: From what I know, even removing $ sign doesn't help  
The latest I heard is that issue was in long being default for double and this causes cascading error in c++ Avro Library

Comment: @HuaZhang I'll see if I can filter that dollar out and see if it that helps. I know Avro for BigQuery is in beta, will this issue resolved before Avro for BigQuery is generally available? This seems to be the upstream issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1478

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Yes the c++ Avro library does have more limitations than the Java library. Before we build the pipe to expose the error messages from the Avro library, please test the file with the C++ Avro library to make sure it can be processed.

Comment: @zenlambda Thanks for the link. It'll be simple to relax the limit in the C++ library, but the Avro specification disallows '$' in the namespace. We'll see what we can do.

Comment: Do you have any idea when those error messages would be exposed to end user? I'm seeing exactly the same case - avro-tools are able to parse particular avro file, while it couldn't be exported to GBQ...

Comment: Working on it. If everything goes smoothly we might be able to release it in a month.

Comment: @HuaZhang: I am facing the issue while loading AVRO files having STRUCT, ARRAY fields with `Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Invalid namespace: .name`.

Comment: Your namespace ".name" starts with ".", which is not allowed by the Avro library.

Comment: @Mikhail Hi I known this is very long time after your comment but I'm currently confronted to the "long being default for double" issue while bq loading avro, and could not found any other pointer to this issue apart from your comment. Do you have any more info to provide ?

Comment: @matthieu.cham - don't have fresh info on this subject - you might want to post question on it

Comment: @Mikhail, just to let you know, I contacted GCP support about this issue last month and GCP has just released a fix for it. I can now load my Avro files, it works fine.